# How do you represent issues without Epics in Jira Roadmap (Jira Classic & Next Gen)

Tags: jira, epics, roadmaps

Ability to represent issues without Epics (be that a task type or bug type) in Jira Roadmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need a Jira issue filter?

```
"Epic Link" is EMPTY
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tool doesn't support having a filter that allows you to view Epics and Stories/Bugs without an Epic next to each other, one trick you could use is to create a "special" epic called something like "No Epic" and put all tickets without an Epic under that.